# Constructing a graph with constraints

Tags: algorithm, graph, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

Well we all know that given n nodes and m edges we can find the no of possible ways to reach from 1 to n using some algorithm like dfs. But consider a case when we have to proceed from back ward side. I mean that we are given no of ways i.e x to reach n from 1 in the question. And we have to find out that n nodes and that m  edges by which if we plot that graph on paper that it has exactly x ways to reach from 1 to n.

Constraints is also there for n and m. n<=300 and m <= 400.and surprisingly contraints for no of ways 'x' is 10^ 18.

Is it possible to form a graph under such constraints?

Note that graph should be a directed acyclic graph with no self loop.

Comment: Please someone answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say W, number of paths, is a power of 2, that is 2^x. Let's try to construct a graph with W paths from 1 to n.

The graph may look like this:

```
1 -> 2,
1 -> 3,
2 -> 4,
3 -> 4
4 -> 5,     
4 -> 6,
5 -> 7,
6 -> 7,
...
```

As you can see, you can create small 'rhombuses', each one multiplies number of paths by 2. If the number is 2^62, you will need 1 + 3 * 62 = 187 nodes and 4 * 62 = 248 edges.

Now, lets say that W = 2^x + 2^y, x < y. Create a rhombuses graph for W' = 2^y. To add 2^x paths, connect the initial vertex with am edge to the vertex that is x rhombuses away from the final one. You can easily calculate, that the number of ways will indeed be 2^x + 2^y.

So for an arbitrary W, rewrite it as a sum of different powers of 2, create a rhombuses graph for the greatest power and add additional edges to add the rest of the powers. It will take you up to 187 nodes (adding edges to the rhombuses graph doesn't affect number of nodes) and 248 edges for the greatest power + 61 for the rest of the powers. It satisfies your constraints.

Comment: can you please implement ur logic when number of paths given is 103?

Comment: What should be do in case when power of 2 is same or more  in two or more numbers? Like a case 2^4 + 2^ 3+ 2^ 3 + 2^3 + 2^ 2.

Comment: Every number has a unique representation as a sum of different powers of 2. Just represent the number in the binary system and read what powers of 2 it has.

Comment: If W = 103 = 64 + 32 + 4 + 2 + 1 = 2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + 2^5 + 2^6. You make a graph consisting of 6 rhombuses, that gives you 64 paths. 1->2, 1->3, 2->4, 3->4, 4->5, 4->6, 5->7, 6->7, 7->8, 7->9, 8->10, 9->10, 10->11, 10->12, 11->13, 12->13, 13->14, 13->15, 14->16, 15->16, 16->17, 16->18, 17->19, 18->19. Then to get the desired result, connect node 1 with nodes: 19 (which gives 2^0 new paths), 16 (2^1 paths), 13 (2^2 paths), 4 (2^5 paths).